# Python Discord Bot - Simply send a message to a channel from a Python Script

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just want to make a Python Discord Bot like this:

```py
# Bot
class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self, TOKEN: str):
    # create / run bot

    def send_msg(self, channel_id: int, message: str):
    # send message to the channel


# Some other Script
my_notifier = DiscordBot("TOKEN")
my_notifier.send_msg(12345, "Hello!")
```

Is this somehow posssible? I don't want to wait for any user messages or stuff to send a message.

UPDATE: I really only want to make the bot send message whenever I call it from a different point in my python files. **I neither want to send a message on start nor in an intervall. Just by something like:** `bot.send_msg(channel, msg)`

Comment: It is possible, and it's not even that hard, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Take a look at Discord webhooks.

Comment: @Łukasz I've looked through the docs but could not find a way to simply send a message without any loop or event comming in. Can you tell me where to look?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send a message you need a object that implements the abc Messagable.
Like (discord.Channel, discord.User, discord.Member)

then you can use the send method on them.
Example:

```
async def send_msg(channel: discord.Channel, message):
    await channel.send(message)
```

And just call the function from any other async function.

```
async def foo():
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    await send_message(channel, "Hello World")
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot to send a message right after its ready. You can do this with to on_ready event.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():  #  Called when internal cache is loaded

    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) #  Gets channel from internal cache
    await channel.send("hello world") #  Sends message to channel


client.run("your_token_here")  # Starts up the bot
```

You may look into the docs from discord.py for more information.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send a message after a specific interval, you can use `tasks` from `discord.ext`.

**An example of using tasks:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks # Importing tasks here

@task.loop(seconds=300) # '300' is the time interval in seconds.
async def send_message():
    """Sends the message every 300 seconds (5 minutes) in a channel."""
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Message")

send_message.start()
client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

Basically this function runs every 300 seconds.

**Reference:**

[discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)